# Erro em declaração findViewById no Android

Tags: android, android-studio, button

Sou novo no Android e estou com uma dificuldade na programação. 
Essa parte do código sempre da erro no `R` do `findViewById`. Ao colocar o mouse sobre o erro aparece a informação `Cannot Revolve simble "R"`, e apenas me da opções de criar uma variável, classe com o nome e etc.

```
@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);

        nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNome);
        RE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtRE);
        senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSenha);

        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);


        button4.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

Comment: Ja Passei por isso uma vez e era um erro no XML do Layout no seu caso pode ser na activity_cadastro ou outra

Comment: Poderia postar seu xml? Por acaso você esta usando o Android Studio Canary?

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente o seu build.gradle não deve estar sincronizado então basta sincronizar, você também pode tentar Build -> Clean Project, ou File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart ou Rebuild Project.

É um bug chato que acontece as vezes.

Comment: Ele pode também dar um make project. Na maioria das vezes resolve.